# Translation for the ability graph

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

During each advertisment break, they display a graph for a stand-user. Unfortunately, some sub-groups don't translate it, and I can't understand what is written there except for the "speed" that is written with Katakana.

Can you please translate it?

And, what do the big capital letters (D, E, D, A, D and C) stand for?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Dimitri's answer, the translations go as I added them to the image below.

[image]

Comment: Durability? I was always sure the bottom one was to do with out of combat utility, because stands such as Mondatta's Thoth, D'arby's Osiris, and Joseph's Hermit Purple always scored very hightly in the bottom segment. I would say that this is a translation error because: 1) durability has never really been an attribute of stands since any damage done to the stand damages the user, and 2) non-combat trick stands score very high in this segment.

Comment: @CameronPowell The bottom one is 持続力 _jizokuryoku_, which you can stick into a translation service or something if you care to check for yourself. I don't watch JoJo, but "durability" seems like a plausible translation. Perhaps alternatively something like "ability to remain active" or "persistence", depending on how stands work.

Comment: Durability is most definitely a stat. Bound Stands have A rank durability because the stand itself is functionally indestructible since they can't be damaged directly.

Answer (score 5):

As my original comment suggested it is indeed a chart of power levels in certain points. The red marking stands for the power division, and it is graded accordingly with a A = Best E= lowest and anything in between.

After a short search I managed to find this image which includes the same stats system on the [jojo wiki page](http://jojo.wikia.com/wiki/Sun), including the translation which is as following (The power levels included are for this card and not for the one you shown in your picture)

Stats are listed clockwise starting from the top

**Stats**

- Destructive Power     A
- Speed     E
- Range     A
- Durability    A
- Precision     E
- Developmental Potential   E

[image]

Comment: In what order did you list them? Can you please match them one-by-one?

Comment: From the top, then clockwise. So destruction is the top stat then the one to the right of it is speed and so on

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the other answers so here is my piece to the other answers:

The letters are the way it grades the Stand according to the stat. The translated text is what determined what the stat is.

The stat at the bottom is the Stands ability. Abilities are something like; Magician Red's fire, Hierophant Greens possession, and (spoiler alert!) Star Platinum's time stop. Hermit Purple's stat in that category is high because of its *ability* to reveal other stand users and make superhuman observations.

Attacking a Stand just hurts the user. Durability is never really brought up as something that a Stand can have since the durability is simply based on the user. I have no idea if there is a Stand with armor so basing a stat on that instead of ability just seems like a mistranslation to me.